# Lorenz system for $s=10$, $r=28$ and $b=8/3$ has unstable critical points, but they never go out of the butterfly shape

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm studying the Lorenz dynamical system, and I'm asking myself if the critical points are unstable critical points.

Considering the theory they are unstable - one eigenvalue $\in \mathbb{R}$ which is negative and 2 complex eigenvalues with a negative real part. But when I look at the critical points the results seem to oscillate around the critical value and never go to $\infty$.

It appears to me it's not an unstable critical point then? Can someone clarify which type of critical points these are?

Answer (score 1):

The Lorenz system has a [strange attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Strange_attractor): this means that trajectories are chaotic but nevertheless stay contained in a set. For the Lorenz system, this attractor has indeed the butterfly shape you notice.

Proving the Lorenz system indeed admits an attractor is a research question that was solved relatively recently. You can see [this Nature paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/35023206) which treats this issue, and which summarizes [the research article by Tucker](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S076444429980439X) (1999) which first proves the existence of such an attractor.

Comment: thanks a lot, but can you then say that the critical points are unstable? Or not?

Comment: The stability of the critical points depend on the parameters. In particular, $\rho < 1$ or $=1$ or $>1$ is important to state stability of the critical points. I suggest you have a look at the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system#Analysis where all this is treated in surprisingly good details

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

That a critical point is unstable doesn't mean that neighbouring trajectories have to diverge to infinity.

The definition of stability (in the sense of Lyapunov) is that for every neighbourhood $U$ of the critical point there is a neighbourhood $V \subseteq U$ of the critical point, such that trajectories starting in $V$ at $t=0$ remain in $U$ for all $t \ge 0$. And "unstable" just means "not stable".

In this case, if you take an open set $U$ that contains the critical point but is small enough to stay clear of the "butterfly", then there is no such $V$. So the critical point is indeed unstable.